# Rails 4 3 years from now on a given date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to find a way to figure out "3 years from now on x date" where x date is not today.

```
def xmas
   self.new_xmas = @given_date + 3.years 
end
```

I'm stuck on how to make sure it's December 25th 3 years from `@given_date`

Comment: If `@given_date` is 2015-12-26, should the date returned be 2018-12-25 or 2019-12-25?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
require 'date'

given_date = Date.today # you can change it to any date
puts "given_date: #{given_date}"
current_year = given_date.year # grab the current year from the given_date
third_xmas_from_given_date = Date.new(current_year + 3, 12, 25) # add 3 years to the current_year (change it according to your need)
puts "third_xmas_from_given_date: #{third_xmas_from_given_date}"
# => given_date: 2015-11-09
# => third_xmas_from_given_date: 2018-12-25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do stuff like Date.new(2015,12,25).next_year(3).

Comment: I should've probably asked how @given_date is formatted first.